# TableLayout doesn't fit the screen

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am a beginner and I have designed a layout that displays the rows from the XML upon the click of a "show" Button.
But when I don't click the show button, I want the table row with id-blank to increase its height to fit the screen.
Please suggest a way to do that.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Row 1 with single column -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Sale Report"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Row 2 with 3 columns -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borders"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/starttime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/stoptime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/show"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:text="show" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:text="back" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/sale_table_data"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/borders"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/sale_report_header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/Yellow" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/particulars"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Particulars"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/voucherNo"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:text="VCH No"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:text="Quantity"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/amount"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Amount"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/blank"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank9"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Particulars"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:text="VCH No"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank11"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:text="Quantity"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank12"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Amount"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank13"
                    android:layout_weight="1.3"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/no_borders" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank2"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Total"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Total"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total_sales"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Amount_value"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/blank3"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You should probably better use, Gridview or ListView with linearLayout or relativelayout